# Create an array of different objects dynamicly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of users and near each user is a checkbox and a input number.
I want to save all data in the process of changing the data from input and checkbox:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { InputNumber, Checkbox } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      nr: "",
      checked: false
    }
  ]);

  function onChangeNr(id, value) {
    console.log("changed", value, id);
    setUser([
      ...user,
      {
        id: id,
        nr: value,
        checked: false
      }
    ]);
  }
  console.log(user);
  function onChangeCheck(e, id) {
    console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}, ${id}`);
    setUser([
      ...user,
      {
        id: id,
        nr: "",
        checked: e.target.checked
      }
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((i) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <p>User {i}</p>
              <InputNumber
                min={1}
                max={10}
                onChange={(id) => onChangeNr(i, id)}
              />
              <Checkbox onChange={(check) => onChangeCheck(check, i)}>
                Checkbox
                  </Checkbox>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now i dont get the disserved result, but i want to get an array with all objects (unique objects). So each time when user change a data, the last value of the same id should override the previous value and at the final to get something like:

```
[
  {id: 1, nr: 1, checked: true},
  {id: 4, nr: 33, checked: true}
]
```

How to get the above result?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-nobel-79is1?file=/src/App.js:0-1165

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with the current version that you have on codesandbox, it seems to work. (Also add `key`s to the `li`s that you are mapping)

Comment: @Twiggeh, the issue is that if i change data 2 times  for one user, i will get in the array 2 objects wth the same ids but i need just the last version. Could you help?

Comment: I misunderstood your question ! I'll post an answer shortly. (You need to find the entry in the array that you need to override )

Answer (score 0):

To override the old state you can't use spread with an array => That will just combine the two arrays into one.

You either need to implement a search that will loop over all of the objects that you have inside the array and find the one that you need to update :

```js
// loop over all entries
for(const i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  // is not the correct id, so not the correct obejct 
  if(array[i].id !== id) continue;

  // found the correct object
  array[i] = {id: i, ...};
}
// update state
setState(array);
```

But that would make js search every element once someone clicks the up / down arrows, so I would recommend that you put the state of the inputs into the array by their indexies:

```js
// we already know the location of the state for the input because we put it into the same index as the key of the input!
array[i] = {id: i, ...}
setState(array)
```

Expample [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-sky-mnu82?file=/src/App.js:856-1055)

```js
const reducer = (state, { type, i, checked, number }) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "setValues":
        // reducer needs a new copy of the state
        const newState = [...state];
        newState[i] = {
          id: i,
          checked: checked ? checked : state[i]?.checked,
          number: number ? number : state[i]?.number
        };
        console.log(newState);
        return newState;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);

return(
  <InputNumber
     min={1}
     max={10}
     onChange={(number) => {
                  dispatch({ type: "setValues", i, number });
              }}
  />)
```